# Excel - finding duplicate values over multiple columns

Tags: excel, list, duplicates

I have a data set containing phone numbers three different users. Each one is its own column in Excel. Eg Alice called the numbers in A:A, Bob called the numbers in B:B and Carol called the numbers in C:C (each column is a different length).

I am trying to determine which phone numbers all 3 have called. I have used unique to filter out duplicates from each list and I know how to find duplicate values over two columns using conditional formatting. But how do I find values that ONLY appear in all three columns?

Clarification:
A mockup of the data is as follows (I can't give out the real data):

| 1 | 5656 | 6464 | | | |-----|------|------|---|---| | 2 | 1 | 456 | | | | 456 | 2 | 2 | | | | 345 | 800 | 1 | | |

I want excel to look through the three columns and find any values which are common to all 3 columns and highlight them.

Comment: It would be great if you provide sample data and expected output. You can put the data in table markdown format. Please consider the following tool: [Table Markdown Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). It helps us to copy the data into excel and to understand better your problem. It helps you because probably you will get more and faster answers. Thanks

Comment: I can't give you the actual dataset as it contains real phone numbers but this is a dummy one. The numbers 1 and 2 appear in all 3 columns. I want to make something that is be able to highlight these values. The number 456 appears in column 1 and 3 but not in 2 - I don't want this highlighted. Is this what you are after with the table markdown generator link you sent me? | 1   | 5656 | 6464 |   |   |
|-----|------|------|---|---|
| 2   | 1    | 456  |   |   |
| 456 | 2    | 2    |   |   |
| 345 | 800  | 1    |   |   |

Comment: thanks, please update the question. Thanks I provided a generic answer, based on your question until you provide more details about the input data and expected output. Yes, the idea is to use mock-up data, we don't need to know the real problem, just a sample that describes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the input data is in the range of `A2:C7`, you can try the following formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(rng, A2:C7, ux, UNIQUE(TOCOL(rng,1)),DROP(REDUCE("", ux, LAMBDA(ac, x, 
 LET(cmp, N(rng=x), ones, SEQUENCE(,ROWS(cmp),1,0), IF(SUM(MMULT(ones, cmp))=3, 
   VSTACK(ac,x), ac)))),1))
```

A **simplified approach** can be achieved using `COUNTIFS`:

```
=LET(rng, A2:C7, ux, UNIQUE(TOCOL(rng,1)), FILTER(ux, COUNTIFS(rng,ux)=3))
```

Here is a sample input data and the corresponding output. *Highlighted* the numbers the formula should return (see conditional formatting formula below):
[image: excel output]

**The previous solutions assumes there are no repeated numbers per column in the input range** (`rng`). Under this assumption you can define a *Conditional formatting* as follow:

```
=SUM(N(A2=$A$2:$C$7))=3
```

If the number can be repeated within a given column, then the first formula can be adjusted as follow:

```
=LET(rng, A2:C7, ux, UNIQUE(TOCOL(rng,1)),DROP(REDUCE("", ux, LAMBDA(ac,x,
  LET(cmp, N(rng=x), ones, SEQUENCE(,ROWS(cmp),1,0), 
    IF(SUM(N(MMULT(ones, cmp) >= 1))=3, VSTACK(ac,x), ac)))),1))
```

Both solutions should work regardless of the number of rows of the input columns. The second input argument of `TOCOL`(`1`) ensures empty cells are not taken into account.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will need some time to unpack it and understand it. There are no repeated numbers (I run a unique on the original data set before I start) so the first solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the ranges, I used just 3 rows to test it.

```
Sub FindCommonNumbers()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rngAlice As Range, rngBob As Range, rngCarol As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim phone As Variant
    ' Create a new dictionary object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Set the range for each user's phone numbers
    Set rngAlice = Range("A1:A3")
    Set rngBob = Range("B1:B3")
    Set rngCarol = Range("C1:C3")

    ' Add the phone numbers from the first column to the dictionary
    For Each cell In rngAlice
        dict(cell.Value) = 1
    Next cell

    ' Check the phone numbers in the second column against the dictionary
    For Each cell In rngBob
        If dict.exists(cell.Value) Then
            dict(cell.Value) = dict(cell.Value) + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Check the phone numbers in the third column against the dictionary
    For Each cell In rngCarol
        If dict.exists(cell.Value) Then
            dict(cell.Value) = dict(cell.Value) + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Print the phone numbers that appear in all three columns
    For Each phone In dict.Keys()
        If dict(phone) = 3 Then
            Debug.Print phone
        End If
    Next phone
End Sub
```